# Hatcher's Algebraic Topology - CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why isnt the topology of the CW complex a metric topology when there is infinitely many edges from a vertex, but it is when there are finitely many edges from a vertex? - page 83

Comment: What part of Hatcher's explanation is unclear to you?

Comment: 1- if the sequences of points inside of the edges do not converge to the vertex in the first place then why does it matter if there are infinitely or finitely many edges from it.. 2- a metric topology should have a neighborhood around a vertex with infinitely or finitely many edges. I think that should be enough for me now (-_-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- if the sequences of points inside of the edges do not converge to
>   the vertex in the first place then why does it matter if there are
>   infinitely or finitely many edges from it.

Hatcher says that "a sequence of points in the interiors of distinct edges ... never converges". If there are only finitely many edges, you can't get an infinite sequence of points in *distinct* edges. You could have an infinite sequence of points on a single edge converging to some point on that edge.

> 2- a metric topology should have a neighborhood around a vertex with
>   infinitely or finitely many edges.

I'm not sure what the question is.

Imagine that you have an infinite set of edges $I_n$, $n \geq 1$, all sharing a vertex $v$. Give each edge the usual metric topology, and I'll write $d$ for the metric on each edge. With the weak topology on the union, the following is an open neighborhood of $v$: take the union over $n$ of the points $x$ on $I_n$ which satisfy $d(x,v) < 1/n$. This will not be open in the metric topology on the union, since it does not contain any $\epsilon$-ball around $v$.

Comment: Could you please tell how come that distance must be $1/n$ rather than another number which would otherwise be making the points inside of a ball.

Comment: It was just an example, it doesn't have to be $1/n$. I wanted a set containing a smaller and smaller piece of each edge. In the definition of weak topology on a graph like this, a set is open if its intersection with each (closed) edge is open in that edge, which is satisfied by the set I described. The $\epsilon$-ball around $v$ is also open for any $\epsilon>0$, but the point is that such balls do not form a basis for the weak topology.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: Hi again, please let me know if i am readin this correctly: the union is open until n = infinity, which is not in the basis.

Comment: $n$ is never infinity in the example I gave. A set which intersects an edge only in the vertex $v$ is certainly not open.

Comment: I have a reply from Hatcher telling me that it is necessary for each point to have a neighborhood containing only finitely many edges.... is that because an infinite sequence of points in the edges is open?? how can I interpret this sequence as open?

Comment: "Containing"? Really? What *exactly* did Hatcher say?

Comment: --meeting finitely many cells--

Comment: This (= "each point must have a neighborhood meeting only finitely many edges") is true for a point in the interior of any edge, but not for a vertex $v$ at which infinitely many edges meet: any neighborhood $U$ of $v$ must intersect the closure of each such edge $I$ in an open subset, and since $U \cap \overline{I}$ contains $v$, it must contain points from $I$ other than $v$.